# I am not able to see OPENTOK subscriber video in my cordova app

Tags: javascript, git, cordova, videochat, opentok

I installed the following plugin in my cordova application:

I am able to connect my devices to the same session but I can't see the subscribers stream on each device screen.

I can only see my own stream.

Here is the code of my index.js:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {

var apiKey = "44684902";
var sessionId = "2_MX40NDY4NDkwMn5-VHVlIE1hciAxMSAwNzo0NjoxNyBQRFQgMjAxNH4wLjIyMDExNzk5fg";
var token =   "T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NDY4NDkwMiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz04OGU4ODg4NTEyYTFhZTcyNWNkOGJiOWQ0ODhlMjA2ZWQ5NjI1YmJmOnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDQwTkRZNE5Ea3dNbjUtVkhWbElFMWhjaUF4TVNBd056bzBOam94TnlCUVJGUWdNakF4Tkg0d0xqSXlNREV4TnprNWZnJmNyZWF0ZV90aW1lPTEzOTQ1NDkyMDAmbm9uY2U9MC4zNTU5Mzc3NzU5MDg3MjIyJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzOTQ1NzA3NjImY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==";

var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey,'myPublisherDiv' );
var session = TB.initSession( sessionId );
session.on({
    'sessionConnected': function( event ){
      session.publish( publisher );
    },
    'streamCreated': function( event ){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + event.stream.streamId);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        session.subscribe( event.stream, div.id);
    }
  });
  session.connect( apiKey, token );

  }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have multiple problems. First, sessionIds should not have any white spaces in them. Second, you session.on method does not have a closing parenthesis `)`.

Cordova is not good at detecting javascript errors, I highly recommend using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) as a debugging tool.

I have included some sample code in the `examples` folder in the repository at  https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok.git

You can try replacing your `www` folder with the `www` folder in the examples directory. The [repository's readme](https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/README.md#sample-code) file has explanations about the sample code and how to get it working.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's correct and working. Just checked and confirmed with other devs. Are you getting any errors? Are you using Cordova CLI or Phonegap?

Comment: I am using Cordova CLI 
I don't have errors but I got these wornings :

THREAD WARNING: exec() call to OpenTokPlugin.publish blocked the main thread for 2411ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context